# Backbone model special url

Tags: javascript, url, backbone.js, collections

I have collection that looks like this:

```
var Players = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Player,
    url: "http://localhost:1337/players",
});
```

And on my server I defined this url

```
app.put("/players/:id/transfer", function (req, res) {});
```

To make PUT request with id I use model.save(), but how can I send request to link above?